# udl file with classic asp ADODB.RecordSet count is 0 but should be higher

Tags: asp-classic, odbc, record, dbconnection

I am working on a classic asp ADODB.RecordSet count is 0 but should be higher (i.e. there should be 1 or more records returned from this query).

How can I tell if the RecordSet successfully opened?  The recordset uses a udl file to connect with the database.  The udl has a "test connection" button, and this button works.

This functionality was working for years, but now has stopped working.  I suspect that the udl connection is bad, but how do I verify that?

CODE:

```vb
SET con1=CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
SET rs_a1=CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

con1.CursorLocation = adUseClient
con1.Open "File Name=c:\WINNT\UDL_DLLS\f1.udl"

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Session_MVRecord_Long WHERE Session = '" & strRSSession & "'"

rs_a1.Open strSQL,con1

'Set Filter to ourRecord1 record-- 
rs_a1.Filter ="ourRecord1Status <> '' OR ourRecord1Yr <> '' OR   ourRecord1Key <> ''"

rs_a1.MoveLast
rs_a1.MoveFirst
IF rs_a1.RecordCount <= 0 THEN%>
'do stuff
```

Comment: Have any of the servers changed? Why would the UDL file change?

Comment: we recently changed servers... not sure whether the dba did anything else with them, etc... waiting to hear back

Comment: Yeah - I think you're going to find this is more a server/possibly IIS issue.

Comment: The dba showed that the udl file itself can connect correctly with the db and should have appropriate privleges.... kind of a mystery

Comment: not sure if this will help anyone else with a similar problem in the future, but it is possible that at least they'll know someone else experienced it... which is always a start...

Comment: Have you tried using it to create an ODBC link on your own PC?